# jQuery addClass to element based on href content

Tags: jquery, href, contains, addclass

I want to addClass to element on load,

If anchor element contains text = Austin Metro

```
<a class="market-display" title="">Austin Metro</a>
```

add class="m-selected" to

```
<a href="#!/austin-metro" class="">Austin Metro</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: the 2nd anchor element with href value is the one I need to add the class, i dont have control over it so the only way to selected is by its href value.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean `textContent`, use [**contains()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

```
$('a:contains(Austin Metro)').addClass('m-select');
```

If you mean `href`, use the [**attribute contains**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector

```
$('[href*="austin-metro"]').addClass('m-select');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var txt = 'Austin Metro';
$('a:contains(' + txt + ')').each(function (i, n) {
    if ($.trim($(n).text()) == txt) {
        $(n).addClass('m-selected');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="market-display" title="">Austin Metro</a>
<a class="market-display" title="">Austin Metro Another</a>
```

If you want check full text,you need to do this